# Brackets Emmet Custom Snippet Configuration Issue

Tags: configuration, adobe-brackets

Here are the steps I took:
 1. Install emmet via extensions manager
 2. Click Emmet menu > preferences
 3. Enter path for extensions. (Tried both custom and actual brackets extensions folder) 
4. Add a snippets.json file to the specified folder in step #3.

```
{
"variables": {
    "lang": "en",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "charset": "UTF-8",
    "indentation": "\t",
    "newline": "\n"
},

"txt": {
    "filters": "txt",
    "profile": "txt",
    "abbreviations": {
        "@i": "@import url(|);"
}
}
```

I am editing a txt file and it is not working when I press `@i<tab>` or Meta+E, what am I missing?

Comment: having the same problem using html.